# why sometime my queries does not execute simply with table name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I cant understand why my second query is not working while other similar queries are working fine can anyone please let me know why these to query behaving differently

query 1

```
function update_record()
{
    $sql="insert into datas.market set title='".stripslashes($title)."',info='".stripslashes($description)."',graphics='"$image."',source_link='".$link."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

query 2

```
function update_record()
{
    $sql="insert into market set title='".stripslashes($title)."',info='".stripslashes($description)."',graphics='"$image."',source_link='".$link."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: **Warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: `insert into .. set = ` is working?

Comment: What error are you getting? My guess is that when running query2, you either have no current DB selected or it's not `datas`.

Comment: have you selected database using mysql_select_db() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between the first query and the second query is that you are explicitly specifying the database name {datas} in the first query and your query works.

So you have not selected the database using after connecting.

```
mysql_select_db('datas');
```

Answer (score 0):

have you selected your database with mysql_select_db()??

Comment: If you answer a question you shouldn't ask another.

Comment: @juergend this can be considered as a *rhetorical question*

Comment: i was just giving him hint to check if he has used this function or not. Because this problem arises form the the given statement